# PHP : ReflectionClass::IS_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT

Tags: php, reflection, interface, abstract-class

I'm trying to figure out how can the constants `IS_IMPLICIT_ABSTRACT` and `IS_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT` of the ReflectionClass be used (if possible at all) to make the `ReflectionClass::isAbstract()` to return true only when the class is abstract because of its definition NOT because it contains abstract methods.

By default, when used with interface, this method returns true and I would like to know whether there is a way of changing this behaviour using these two pre-defined constants.

Example would be:

```
interface BookInterface {

    public function getTitle();

    public function getAuthors();

    public function getYear();

    public function getIsbn();

}

$book = new ReflectionClass('BookInterface');
$book->isAbstract() // returns true
```

Obviously `ReflectionClass::isAbstract()` doesn't take any arguments - so not quite sure if it's possible.

Comment: What did you try ? Do you have some code ?

Comment: Yes - sorry - just updated the post.

Comment: No problem, I'm not a specialist in this domain and can't give an answer anyway... Sorry myself.

Comment: `$book->isAbstract() && !$book->isInterface()`

Comment: Well yes, but what is the purpose of these constants then?